# Why might a repressive order allow for flamboyant newscasters?

Tags: science-fiction, culture, communication, dystopia, telecommunications

Thanks in advance and sorry if this isn't within the scope of the forum, I'm new but I've lurked so I totally get it if this doesn't really fit.

Anyway, let's get into it. Setting is a far-future solar system with a number of planets and interworld powers controlling them. One such power is a military/religious order (let's call them Bird Cult) that runs an interworld broadcasting corporation which would serve as the primary "general" news source-- not openly biased towards a particular sect, broadcast in a number of common languages, focusing on general world events. Notably, Bird Cult due to silly and ultimately irrelevant factors, believes themselves to be descended from a great bird-deity, with some people having stronger genetic traces of it (this is unverifiable). These people are raised from birth to believe that they are superior and inherently meant for military and religious positions of power; they wear military clothing and occasionally eagle- or vulture-like ritual masks. Others in this society are treated as lesser by virtue of their birth, and often work menial jobs in service to the higher class.

So, here's where things get silly. The general news source has two main newscasters/personalities who are more than a bit flamboyant in both dress (bright colors, garish patterns, peacock and parrot motifs) and beliefs (both on-the-air boisterousness and private disbelief/lack of fealty to Bird Cult). They are not part of the upper class. Why might Bird Cult allow some of their most prominent representatives to other cultures and world powers be "low-bloods" who flaunt tradition, rather than instating more conformist anchors of the higher class?

Comment: Is a newscaster considered to be a "military and religions position of power"?  If not, then  wouldn't it have to be a "low-blood" in the position?

Comment: Hello @BZawhi, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference, the choices of individuals and organizations are off-topic (they're story based, meaning why the choice is made depends on narrative necessity, not a fundamental rule of the world). Please read through our [tour] and the following two Help Center pages to better understand the limits of this site: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. Note that reading the *Hunger Games* books gives a good reason for this situation. Cheers.

Comment: How is this not "diversity and inclusion" today?

Answer (score 7):

**Controlled Opposition**

The Bird Cult, in order to maintain a facade of openness and Tolerant (despite the open secret that's not really like that) - has these presenters on like Sock Puppets - that way when certain factions get a bit uppity - they can point to it and say:

"But if we were truly like this - we wouldn't allow our main news presenters to be those two"

Comment: "Make sure the lower class doesn't revolt". "Put some citizens of the lower class in a position that everyone can see and make them believe that they can also achieve it"

Answer (score 7):

**Bread and Circuses**

Throughout history, there has never been a revolt or revolution that occurred when people are comfortable, and their bellies are fed.  A government that does not provide these is not long for this world.  The government that does... they can get away with the worst abuses of power.  Why disappear the dissidents who believed that a guy who was executed by the state is their god when you have lions and crowds of people who want to spend their Saturdays with their kids watching mind numbing entertainment.  You kill two birds with one stone (one in the literal sense) and the price of admission can help keep the coffers full (tell the masses that the money goes to pay for the re-education... I mean schools... yeah... schools.  People want to see the dissidents die anyway, and if you think that's barbaric you clearly don't think of the children.  Won't somebody please think of the children!)."

All news is meant to entertain.  If you don't believe, then why does every morning show anchor look like they're having way too much fun for a person who has to wake up at 3:30 AM to get to work on time for a 7:00 AM broadcast?  Because who the fuck wants to watch people grumbling about the morning while telling you how many people died in a building collapse in a country they never heard of.

And the same reason why cable news prime time is filled with opinionated talking heads... after a hard day of work and getting chewed out by the boss who doesn't have a clue how to do your job but somehow knows you did it wrong, who wants to come home and hear praise of the glorious leader that you don't agree with?

Real world news in developed, democratic nations exists to entertain and inform... in that order.  Why should fake news in a dictatorial theocratic hellhole that spout real fake news not be any different?   Afterall, you want to model your anchors after birds that are known for mindlessly repeating babble it is taught by it's owners and one entirely known for it's sex appeal.  Just like every tv news anchor in the real world.

Comment: "The government that does... they can get away with the worst abuses of power." This reminds me of Machiavelli's *The Prince*. To paraphrase him: while it is better to be feared than loved if you can't have both, you must absolutely avoid being *hated*. If the people hate you, they will endure any level of pain and suffering to see you overthrown.

Answer (score 3):

**Court jesters**

Gaudy clothing and jabbing at the great is permitted to clowns and jesters.   As a relief valve.

Also as a way of indicating news is not important.  Their attention grabbing detracts from what they say, and the less attention the news gets the more they are rewarded

Answer (score 1):

**To discredit the truth.**

Yes, this government magnanimously lets the opposition have a voice… or so it claims. In reality, the Bird Cult has set it up to be as laughable and "obviously" fake as possible. Their boisterousness, combined with the underlying implications of the birds they represent (as @hszmv pointed out, parrots blindly repeat whatever they're told, and peacocks are dumb, sex-obsessed, and petty), makes the talking heads seem inherently untrustworthy. Further reinforcing the public's impression, the talking heads heavily editorialize the news they present. The end result is that they come off as more of a comedic farce than serious news.

On the other hand, the pro-Bird Cult news stations are reserved and staid. Furthermore, they make *absolutely* sure that the factual content of their broadcasts is accurate whenever possible, limiting their editorializing to how they interpret these facts. As a result, while everybody watches Parrot and Peacock™ to get some cheap laughs, they go to the pro-Bird Cult sources for their actual news.

Answer (score 0):

**Marketing**

Viewers like these two! So in order to make sure people keep watching, they keep them on the air.

Answer (score 0):

> Why might Bird Cult allow some of their most prominent representatives to other cultures and world powers be "low-bloods" who flaunt tradition, rather than instating more conformist anchors of the higher class?

Because they see other cultures and world powers as inherently inferior unbelievers. They aren't very concerned about the image they're projecting because it doesn't really matter what the outsiders think. The cultists in charge occupy religious and military positions, which would make them predisposed to deal with outside powers by force rather than diplomacy, and if the outside powers are too strong to dominate, just not deal with them at all.

As for the domestic audience, they are also inferior, so as long as they aren't revolting, who cares what they think. As an added bonus, the populace seem to find the newscasters entertaining, so that's good. As others have said, bread and circuses. Also, if the flamboyant manner of the newscasters makes this military-religious cult seem a bit less scary, that's another bonus.